# Get Text of Form Field

Tags: javascript, forms, element

i'm a newbie to javascript.  i'm trying to make a form & access the values of text fields.  that didn't work. so, i added a little test script to show an alert with just the value of the field.  that doesn't work either.  i'm following the docs and i can't figure out why it doesn't work.  i tried it several different ways. which i show as comments.  none of them worked.  any help greatly appreciated.

```
<html>

<head>


</head>

<body>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
//<!-- hide from older browsers

alert("document.TalkNow.explain1")
alert("HI")

var stmtArray = new Array
var permWords = new Array ["always","never"]
var neutralWords = new Array ["sometimes","often","frequent"]
var pervasiveWords = new Array ["every", "all", "each"]
var localWords = new Array ["some", "few"]
var internal = new Array ["I","me"]
var external = new Array ["He", "She", "They"]
var stories[3] = new Array


// function Scrolling essage Footer
function parseExplain(){
    //alert(document.forms[0].elements[0])

}


// parser function

//-->
</script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
//<!-- hide from older browsers

//var text=document.getElementById("TalkNow").elements[0].value
//var text=document.getElementById("TalkNow").elements[0].value
//var text=document.forms["TalkNow"]["explain1"].value
//alert(text)

//alert(document."TalkNow".explain1.value)
//alert(document."TalkNow".elements[0].value)
//alert(document.form[0].elements[0])



//-->
</script>

<p id="demo"></p>

<form name="TalkNow" action="#">
 <p>
 <h2>What happened?</h2>
 <input type="textarea" name="event" size="80">
 </p>
 <h2>How you explain this?</h2>
 <input type="text" name="explain1" size="80">
 <input type="button" name="Assess" value="Evaluate" onClick="parseExplain()"> 
 <p>
 <h2>What happened next?</h2>
 <input type="textarea" name="event" size="80">
 <p>
 <h2>How you explain this?</h2>
 <input type="text" name="explain2" size="80">
 <input type="button" name="Assess" value="Evaluate"> 
 <p>
 <h2>What happened after that?</h2>
 <input type="textarea" name="event" size="80">
 <p>
 <h2>How you explain this?</h2>
 <input type="text" size="80">
 <input type="button" name="Assess" value="Evaluate"> 
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I recommend jQuery, get that on the page first - then accessing elements and their values becomes a lot easier. This is the tip of the iceberg what it's useful for.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

First, set the ID to talkNow, rather than the name.

Then, use the following JavaScript to access it's value.

```
document.getElementById("talkNow").value;
```

Good Luck!

Comment: i tried that too.  is there a difference between id & name?

Comment: does the browser make a difference?  i'm using firefox 33.0.2

Comment: Yes and No. ID and name are different, and it does not matter what browser you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the javascript after the html is generated, also I can see in the commented script that you are using points to add strings together, in javascript you can just use the + sign. 
Here:

```
alert("document.TalkNow.explain1")
```

you are just alerting a string, it is in between exclamation marks so it will be handled as a string, when you remove these it will be handled as command, though it wont alert anything usefull because you are only getting the element and not the value of the element.

Comment: that didnt work. just gave me an alert box that says "document.TalkNow.explain1"  but i don't get the value of what should be in TalkNow